# Raspbian wifi driver for 0bda:f179

Tags: angular, driver, raspberry-pi3

I recently brought my raspberry pi 3 model B+ and my wifi adapter which is a Realtek RTL8188

It doesn't work when I plug into the Raspberry pi, but works instantly on my Windows 10 Laptop

(More information)
Terminal:
lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

uname -r

```
4.14.34-v7+
```

dmesg

```
[ 3063.390743] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
[ 3063.521627] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=f179
[ 3063.521643] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3063.521652] usb 1-1.3: Product: 802.11n
[ 3063.521661] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 3063.521669] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 000F004035AE
```

sudo lshw

```
 *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: Generic USB device
         product: 802.11n
         vendor: Realtek
         physical id: 3
         bus info: usb@1:1.3
         version: 0.00
         serial: 000F004035AE
         capabilities: usb-2.00
         configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

I have already done my fair share of research on it

/ It says the person also trying to install the driver by it's kernel version is at 3.8.0-30-generic
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172877

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.14.34-v7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.14.34-v7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.14.34-v7'
E: Package 'linux-headers-generic' has no installation candidate


wget https://realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304.googlecode.com/files/rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb

--2018-06-11 13:27:39--  https://realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304.googlecode.com/files/rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb
Resolving realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304.googlecode.com (realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304.googlecode.com)... 74.125.200.82, 2404:6800:4003:c00::52
Connecting to realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304.googlecode.com (realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304.googlecode.com)|74.125.200.82|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-06-11 13:27:40 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site for Q&A about programming, not general computing. Try reading the description of the [tag:raspberry-pi3] tag that you applied to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to make it work for 3 hours on my Raspberry Pi 2, I found the correct driver:

- 0bda:f179 uses Realtek 8188FU -> look for this particular driver for your version of Raspbian. Generic versions and 8188EU will not work.
  There is a script by MrEngman in https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=62371 that detects the correct version and downloads it automatically.